# Walk a folder structure, rename files to match sub-folder, keep file extension

Tags: python, windows-10

I am new to python and coding, as a first project, I am looking to create a python script which will traverse a folder structure and look inside each sub-folder and rename the files within to match the name of the sub-folder.

Example folder structure:

```
root folder
├── first sub-folder (Batman)
│   ├── filename.extension (joker.pdf)
│   └── filename.differentExtension (bane.jpg)
│
└── second sub-folder
    ├── filename.extension
    └── filename.differentExtension
```

So after the script has completed, the result would look like the below:

```
root folder
├── first sub-folder (Batman)
│   ├── filename.extension (Batman.pdf)
│   └── filename.differentExtension (Batman.jpg)
│
└── second sub-folder
    ├── filename.extension
    └── filename.differentExtension
```

I am looking for recommendations into how to approach this, I was thinking of using os.path.splitext to seperate the filename from the file extension, but i'm unsure how to change the filename to the sub-folder value and then concatenate the filename and file extension back together.

Comment: Yes, use `os.path.splitext()` and look into `os.walk` - these will be your friends.

Comment: Thanks for the direction S3DEV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `os.walk`, and `ntpath` with a [recursive](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) function, to walk all directories and subdirectories...renaming as you go. The following code can absolutely be compressed...but I wanted to make it more explicit to help your understanding of what's happening.

```
import os
import ntpath

print(os.getcwd()) # Information for testing
rootDir = "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test" # Will start here

# Create a recursive function. 
# This function will call itself, to pass in new directories it finds
def walkit(rootDir):
    # os.walk gives you the name of the directory it's in, 
    # all the subdirs (as a list), 
    # and all the filesnames (as a list)
    for thisDir, thisDir_subDirs, thisDir_files in os.walk(rootDir):
        print("---------------------------")
        print("This Directory =", thisDir, "\nSubdirectories:", thisDir_subDirs, "\nFiles:", thisDir_files)
        # Loop through and change the filenames first
        for filename in thisDir_files:
            # Get JUST the filename with extension
            basename        = ntpath.basename(filename)
            # Split the filename into name + extension 
            name, ext   = os.path.splitext(basename) 
            # Next split the last directory off the full directory path. 
            # Returns a tuple, so you have to take the second element "[1]"
            newname = ntpath.split(thisDir)[1]
            # Python join to create a new name + extension
            newfilename = ''.join([newname, ext])
            # Set the source by joining the current FULL directory path and the FULL old name
            src = os.path.join(thisDir, filename)
            # Set the destination by joining the current FULL path plus the FULL NEW name
            dst = os.path.join(thisDir, newfilename)
            try: # Use try except to catch problems
                print("Renaming '{}' to '{}' ... ".format(src, dst), end = '') 
                os.rename(src, dst) # Rename the file
                print("OK") # Worked
            except Exception as e: # Failed
                print("FAILED! (ERROR:{})".format(str(e)))

        # Now cycle through the list of subdirectories and 
        # send each directory back into the walkit function. 
        # As each loop calls the function, it winds itself a new level deep
        # Each time the function finishes, it "UNwinds" itself one level        
        for rootDir in thisDir_subDirs:
            walkit(rootDir)

# Start the first iteratin by calling the function with the first directory to be parsed
walkit(rootDir)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/home/user/eclipse-workspace/
---------------------------
This Directory = /home/user/eclipse-workspace/test 
Subdirectories: ['robin', 'batman'] 
Files: []
---------------------------
This Directory = /home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/robin 
Subdirectories: [] 
Files: ['riddler.jpg', 'penguin.pdf']
ext= .jpg
newfilename =  robin.jpg
Renaming '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/robin/riddler.jpg' to '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/robin/robin.jpg' ... OK
ext= .pdf
newfilename =  robin.pdf
Renaming '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/robin/penguin.pdf' to '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/robin/robin.pdf' ... OK
---------------------------
This Directory = /home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/batman 
Subdirectories: [] 
Files: ['joker.pdf', 'bane.jpg']
ext= .pdf
newfilename =  batman.pdf
Renaming '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/batman/joker.pdf' to '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/batman/batman.pdf' ... OK
ext= .jpg
newfilename =  batman.jpg
Renaming '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/batman/bane.jpg' to '/home/user/eclipse-workspace/test/batman/batman.jpg' ... OK
```

Comment: I don't completly understand this just yet, I will break down each section and read up on the different modules that have been used.

I have successfully ran the script and the output is very easy to run through and spot any failures.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to make your code very easy to read with good descriptions, it makes it a lot easier to breakdown for a newbie, i'm still getting my head around the different symbols and there uses.

Answer (score 2):

`pathlib` is a modern module that aggregates nearly all of the path related tools in Python, which are spread out across `os.path`, `os`, `ntpath`, etc.  See a [table of comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module) here.

*CAUTION: You should always take great care when using destructive I/O operations such as renaming and deleting files.  Know what your code is doing and test it first in isolation to prevent mistaken loss of files.  Apply code from any answers here at your own risk.*

**Given**

```
import pathlib
```

A directory of subfolders and files in `test_dc/`:

[image]

**Code**

```
def rename_files(target_dirpath: str, ignore_pattern: str="^*"):
    """Return a dict and rename files."""
    root_dirpath = pathlib.Path(target_dirpath).expanduser()
    renamed_paths = {}

    for path in root_dirpath.rglob("*"):

        if not path.is_file() or path.match(ignore_pattern):
            continue
        
        # Parse new filename
        dirpath = path.parent
        suffix = path.suffix
        dirname = dirpath.stem
        filename = dirname + suffix
        filepath = dirpath / filename
        
        # Rename
        renamed_paths[str(path)] = filepath.name
        path.rename(filepath)
    return renamed_paths
```

**Demo**

```
print(rename_files("~/test_dc/"))
#{
#     'home/user/test_dc/batman/bane.jpg': 'batman.jpg',
#     'home/user/test_dc/batman/joker.txt': 'batman.txt',
#     'home/user/test_dc/robin/catwoman.png': 'robin.png',
#     'home/user/test_dc/robin/penguin.txt': 'robin.txt'
#}
```

[image]

---

**Details**

The goal is to rename a file with the name of its containing sub-folder. Here we recursively traverse a folder to get file paths.  Since the sub-folders are part of the path, we extract the sub-folder name, make a new filepath and rename the path.

See also some of the tools used in this demo:

- [`pathlib.Path().rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob): use a loop to recursively iterate the root folder and its sub-folders.
- [`pathlib.Path().rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename): rename files with a target (sub-folder) name.
- [`pathlib.Path().name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name): the final filename + extension or directory name (aka basename)
- [`pathlib.Path().stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem): filename or directory name
- [`pathlib.Path().suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffixes): the extension
- Optionally add regex patterns of files to ignore, e.g. `*.pyc`

Comment: Thanks pylang, I've not been able to run this successfully, however once I fully understand RightmireM's answer, I will study your answer, thanks for sharing how you'd solve the proposed problem.

Comment: Sure.  Let me know what issues you have, I'll try to assist.

Comment: When I run the script, I don't get an output like your demo suggests, however I can confirm it does rename the files, I have ran the script from within the terminal of vs code and also using command prompt (Windows).

Am I correct in thinking after the for loop is exited 

`return renamed_paths` 

is executed and this should list everything in the _renamed_paths_ variable which after successful execution of the for loop should be all the renamed files?

Comment: This is just a function.  You can run it interactively.  To run it in a script you'd have to call the function.  To see the dict in console, you can print the results, e.g. `print(rename_files("./test_dc/"))`.  The dict output is really just a side-effect of the function's true purpose, to rename files.

Answer (score 1):

you approach is correct.

```
root = "root path"
names = []
paths = []
for d in os.listdir(root):
    names.append(d)
    paths.append(os.path.join(root, d))
for i in range(len(names)):
    for j in os.listdir(paths[i]):
        ext = os.path.splitext(j)[-1]
        os.rename(os.path.join(paths[i], j), os.path.join(paths[i], (names[i]+str(ext))))
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `os.path.splitext()` in case the filename has an unexpected format.

Comment: Thanks Eshaka for taking the time to post your solution, however i'm not yet at the level to interperate your script, Is it possible for you to add a few comments to help me understand?

Answer (score 1):

Another small method should work well when there is 2 level directory as stated in your example.

```
root_folder = "root folder\\"                                    #root folder
for sub_folder in os.listdir(root_folder):                       #get subfolders
    path = os.path.join(root_folder ,sub_folder)
    for file in os.listdir(path):                                #get files in subfolder
        file_name = file[:file.rfind(".")]                       #get filename
        extension = file[file.rfind("."):]                       #get extension of file
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,file),os.path.join(path,"{}{}".format(sub_folder,extension))) #rename
```